# Appended row in table view of mobile application must retain permanently (titanium)

Tags: javascript, android, dom-events, mobile-application, appcelerator-mobile

I am using titanium for developing Android application. I am using following code for displaying data and using table view.When I click on comment_btn a new row get appended in table view.it works fine.But when I click back button or go to another window and again come back to same window where I added my new row that newly added row is not retain.I also tried 
**insertRowAfter** but it gives me same result.I used following code:

```
for (var i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({height:'auto',className:"row"});
    var comments = Ti.UI.createLabel(
    {
        text:'new comment',
        height:'auto',
        font:{fontSize:12, fontFamily:'Helvetica Neue'},
        color:'#000',
        width:'auto',
        textAlign:'left',
        top:10,
        left:40,
    });row.add(comments);
}
comment_table.setData(data);
commnet.add(comment_table);
var comment_btn = Titanium.UI.createButton(
{
    title:'comment',
    height:60,
    width:60,
    bottom:-5,
    left:-2,
});
comment.add(comment_btn);
var comment_box = Titanium.UI.createTextArea({
    borderRadius:5,
    backgroundColor:'#EEE',
    editable: true,
    height:30,
    width:200,
    top:10,
    font:{fontSize:15,fontFamily:'Marker Felt'},
    color:'#000',
    keyboardType:Titanium.UI.KEYBOARD_DEFAULT,
    returnKeyType:Titanium.UI.RETURNKEY_DEFAULT,
    borderRadius:5, 
});
comment.add(comment_box);
comment_btn.addEventListener('click', function()
{
    comment_table.appendRow({title:comment_box.value});
    //comment_table.insertRowAfter(3,{'title':comment_box.value});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The Object must be of type Row for: `comment_table.appendRow(ROW_TYPE_OBJECT)`.
2. If you are going back(Assuming pressing back button) then current window gets closed hence
   all children of that window say views, buttons, table will be removed.
3. Assume current window with Tableview as widnow1, Now you opens window2, And If you are
   transiting from window2 to window1 then you can see table with new appended row in
   window1.

**Solution:**

1. Create a global array(`data[]`) which holds the rows and rows which you are going to 
   append.
2. When loading current window1,check if data is null.
3. If data is not null then load your tableview from global array data
   `tableview.setData(data)`, else load fresh rows.